# Sentinel 2 imagery not filling the whole square Google Earth Engine JavaScript

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2, google

[image: not a full square of image]

Sentinel 2 satellite should be able to display that region of the square too because of the way the satellite travels and scans each region. Why is this happening?

```js
var start_date = "2016-05-12"
var end_date = "2016-05-13"
var PixelPErc = 100
//displays cordinates
print(geometry.geometries().get(0))
print((ee.ImageCollection(S2).filterDate(start_date, end_date).filterBounds(geometry).filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', PixelPErc)).toList(1000).getInfo()))

// Let’s define the image collection we are working with by writing this command.
// We are creating a new variable 'image' that will come from the L8 collection we have imported
var image = ee.ImageCollection(S2

  // We will then include a filter to get only images in the date range we are interested in
  .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
  //.print(S2)

  // Next we include a geographic filter to narrow the search to images at the location of our ROI point
  .filterBounds(geometry)

  // Next we will also sort the collection by a metadata property, in our case cloud cover is a very useful one
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', PixelPErc)))

// Now lets select the first image out of this collection - i.e. the most cloud free image in the date range
// .first());

// And let's print the image to the console.
print("A Sentinel scene:", image);

// Define visualization parameters in a JavaScript dictionary for true colour rendering. 
// Bands 4,3, and 2 are needed for RGB (true colour composite).
var trueColour = {
  bands: ["B4", "B3", "B2"],
  min: 250,
  max: 8500,
  gamma: 1.5,
  opacity: 1
};

// Define visualization parameters in a JavaScript dictionary for true colour rendering. 
// Bands 8,4,3 are needed for RGB (false colour composite).
var falseColour = {
  bands: ["B8", "B4", "B3"],
  min: 250,
  max: 8500,
  gamma: 1.5,
  opacity: 1
};

var SWIR = {
  bands: ["B12", "B8A", "B4"],
  min: 250,
  max: 8500,
  gamma: 1.5,
  opacity: 1
};

var VNIR = {
  bands: ["B6", "B7", "B8A"],
  min: 250,
  max: 8500,
  gamma: 1.5,
  opacity: 1
};

// Centre the scene to the ROI
Map.centerObject(geometry, 10);

// Add the image to the map, using the visualization parameters.
Map.addLayer(image, trueColour, "true-colour image");

// Add the image to the map, using the visualization parameters.
Map.addLayer(image, falseColour, "false-colour image");

Map.addLayer(image, SWIR, "SWIR image");

Map.addLayer(image, VNIR, "VNIR image");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't execute, so your problem is difficult to reproduce, and I had to make some guesses on what you're actually asking. Please take some more time in the future when writing your questions. Make sure your problem statement is clear, include **all relevant code** to reproduce your question, but **only relevant code**. Don't forget to share any eventual assets used, and try to include a Code Editor link (using the `Get Link` button).

The reason your image doesn't cover your geometry is because `filterBounds()` keeps images that intersect your geometry, they don't need to contain the geometry. Your date range is so short that you don't get imagery to cover the whole geometry.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
  [12.211653910675228, 42.421505951707665],
  [12.211653910675228, 41.61346681492115],
  [13.211409770050228, 41.61346681492115],
  [13.211409770050228, 42.421505951707665]
]])

var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2022-05-03', '2022-05-04')
  // .filterDate('2022-04-03', '2022-05-04') // If you switch to this date range, you'll get image for the whole geometry
  .mosaic()
Map.addLayer(geometry, null, 'geometry')
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', max: 3000}, 'image')
Map.centerObject(geometry)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5ba6ff5106c8c0e767b70253adfffe35